# hibernate QuerySyntaxException - Field is not mapped

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am getting a QuerySyntaxException trying to run a HQL query against 2 tables:

```
 select p from ProductEntity p join p.categories c, p.productType t where c.name = :category and t.name = :type
```

The exception is:

```
 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: p.productType is not mapped
```

My entities are set up so I thought everything was mapped:

```
 Product Entity:

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
private ProductTypeEntity productType;

Product Type Entity:

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "productType")
private Set<ProductEntity> products = new HashSet<ProductEntity>(0);
```

I want to select all products with a category of 'x' and a product type of 'y'.

A product has a set of categories and it also has a single type, although a type can apply to many products.

Can anyone see what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are missing `join` keyword before `p.productType t`.

So, the query should be:

```
select p from ProductEntity p join p.categories c join p.productType t where c.name = :category and t.name = :type
```

Later edit: removed comma after `p.categories c`

Comment: I had already tried that: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: join near line 1, column 94

Comment: oh, please remove `comma` after c

Comment: Thanks, I cant believe it was just that comma :(